# Ksp and Precipitation

Tags: solubility

> A scientist slowly adds dissolved NaCl to form a solution of AgNO3. If a precipitate begins to form when the NaCl concentration is $5.5*10^{-4}$ M, what is the concentration of Ag$^+$ in the solution? K$_{sp}$ = $1.8*10^{-10}$.

A) $3.3*10^{-7}$ M
B) $9.39*10^{-14}$ M
C) $3.1*10^{6}$ M
D) $6.0*10^{-6}$ M
E) $6.0*10^{-8}$ M

I've been having trouble with this problem. I think it has something to do with the common ion effect, but I'm not sure.

Here's my current understanding:
The reaction is:  $\hspace 5mm$  NaCl(aq) + AgNO3 (aq) $\rightarrow$ NaNO3 (aq) + AgCl (s)
This makes the net ionic reaction:  $\hspace 5mm$ Cl$^-$ (aq) + Ag$^+$ (aq) $\rightarrow$ AgCl (s)
Whenever the concentration of NaCl, and therefore Cl$^-$ ions reaches $5.5*10^{-4}$ M, the Chlorine ions start reacting with the Silver ions. My best guess is that is when the maximum solubility is reached for AgCl, AgCl has to start precipitating out due to le Chatelier's principle. This means that [Ag$^{+}$]*$5.5*10^{-4}$ = $1.8*10^{-10}$, meaning that [Ag$^{+}$] = $3.27273*10^{-4}$ M, for an answer of A. Is this a valid line of reasoning?

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much correct.

Comment: Useful links for text and formula formatting (not to be applied to titles):
 [Notation basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) ,  [Formatting of math/chem expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)  and 
[upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized)

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solubility_equilibrium